# Algebra - Group Theory help... Intersection notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do you write $\{g ∈ G : \mu (Hx,g) = Hx,∀x∈G \}$ in intersection form? where $\mu (Hx,g) = Hgx$

Comment: What is $\mu(Hx,g)$?

Comment: @Douglas : I removed your question about the typesetting from the question ; you need to put math formulas between cash symbols for them to show up correctly (and the { } symbols need to be written \{ \} ). See my edit to understand how to write it.

Comment: Well my question is Let K := {g (element of) G : µ(Hx, g) = Hx, (for all)x (element of) G}
Show that K is a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: You should really clarify what $\mu(Hx, g)$ means. I just saw the typesetting of your comment ; note that you can also edit comments and "element of" is written with \in, "for all" with \forall.

Comment: µ(Hx, g) := Hxg

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva can you help? Or have I not given enough information still...

Answer (score 0):

This set just equals $H$. The $x$ is irrelevant since it sits on the right hand side.
Probably you mean $\mu(Hx,g)=Hxg$? Then the set is equal to $\bigcap_{x \in G} x^{-1} H x$.